# Xamarin Forms Cross Platform Persistent Storage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a way to persist settings (KVPs) in a Xamarin Forms app.
I'd like the settings to be easily bound and notified, very much like the SimpleSettings NuGet.  The only problem with SimpleSettings is that it doesn't support UWP.  Any ideas on a package that supports all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SettingsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin) by James Montemagno. It's supported on all platform and uses the native setttings API's (NSUserDefaults, SharedPreferences, etc) in the background.

Here's the documentation on how to get started: https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/SettingsPlugin/